# Captions for an youtube video using YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube-api

Hi after so much research i found this link which gives an xml version of the captions with timelines but when i tried to get the same thing using `file_get_contents` function in php it just gives only text files.

```
http://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=7GIDDaF26zE&lang=en
```

Can any one help me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) reads the entire file into a string. If you wanted to get the video's captions directly, you could use [`captions.download`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download), but you either have to be the owner of the video or the owner has to enable third-party contributions for the captions.